# React Native Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a React Native component for iOS that accepts image input a message saying `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` I am quite new to React Native, so I don't understand what the "key" prop is and where to add it.

Here is my code:

```
function ImageInputList({ imageUris = [], onRemoveImage, onAddImage }) {
  const scrollView = useRef();

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollView}
        horizontal
        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView.current.scrollToEnd()}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {imageUris.map((uri) => (
            <View key={uri} style={styles.image}>
              <ImageInput
                imageUri={uri}
                onChangeImage={() => onRemoveImage(uri)}
              />
            </View>
          ))}
          <ImageInput onChangeImage={(uri) => onAddImage(uri)} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I understand that the `map()` requires a key, but I don't understand what a key does, or how to insert it. I am following a tutorial, and it works for the person who I am following.
I think most of the code is working as expected, but on my form which is showing this component, when an image is selected, no picture of the image shows up. I have looked at multiple similar questions, but I think that in this script already has a key added from the uri.

Comment: You're already providing a key, which is `uri`, in your `<View` node, which is correct. The issue is probably just a duplicate value in that array. Hence, not unique, which gives that warning. You should either not allow users to duplicate URIs, or provide a more structured data object in that array that has unique IDs you can use as keys instead of the URI itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)